# Google Cloud CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API

Tags: google-api, wildfly

I am trying to use **Google Cloud CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API.**

I already have Google cloud running Account. 
I enabled CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API service and generated Service account keys and downloaded locally.

I ham using Goggle default program

```
LanguageServiceClient language = LanguageServiceClient.create();

// The text to analyze
String text = "My stay at this hotel was not so good";
Document doc = Document.newBuilder().setContent(text).setType(Type.PLAIN_TEXT).build();

// Detects the sentiment of the text
Sentiment sentiment = language.analyzeSentiment(doc).getDocumentSentiment();

System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
System.out.printf("Sentiment: %s, %s%n", sentiment.getScore(), sentiment.getMagnitude());
```

I am using **Eclipse** as IDE on **Mac**

When I run application I got error

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute E
ngine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs
/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I even added **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** as export in Terminal and on using "**printenv**" it shows the Path like this

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/temp/Downloads/Sentiment-0e556940c1d8.json
```

Still it wasn't working with some hit and trial method I found out that in eclipse we can configure run.

There I have added environment variable and after that when I run program it works fine.

**Now MY problem is I am implementing that code inside J2EE project and that ear file is to  deploy in Wildfly. 
I am again getting same error. Now I dont know where to set enviromnet variable in Wildfly or where???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to set up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as environment variable inside Wildfly

1. **If you are running server through Eclipse**

   - Open Wildfly Server setting by double clicking your server inside
     Server Tab
   - Click "Open Launch Configuration"
   - Move to "Environment" tab and add new variable as **key value** pair

   eg

   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  /Users/temp/Downloads/Sentiment-0e556940c1d8.json
2. **If you are running server using terminal**

   By default Wildfly looks for additional setting inside standalone.conf file.

   just open *wildfly/bin/standalone.conf* file and add following line

   *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/temp/Downloads/Sentiment-0e556940c1d8.json*

Thats it. You are good to go.....